# Rashi Script in Aruch Hashulchan

Tags: authorship, publications, aruch-hashulchan

In my edition of the Aruch Hashulchan, there is often a paragraph that has Rashi script written inside brackets (see pic). What is the Rashi script? Is it the *mechaber* or someone/something else? I couldn't find any info on this in the opening pages of the Oz VeHadar edition of the Aruch Hashulchan.

[image]

Comment: It would seem from the one in the next sif (21:3) as well as many others that it is the Mechaber himself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This exists in all editions of the Aruch HaShulchan. See for example [the first page](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=105788&pagenum=2) of this older edition.

Perhaps you couldn't find anything on this because unexpectedly the introduction to the work is in Choshen Mishpat. This is because it was the first section of Shulchan Aruch that he wrote.

[There, note 8](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=602346&pagenum=12), he explains that he put these pieces in square brackets (and a different font), because they're not specifically to tell you the final *halacha*. Rather, they're his novella in understanding of the gemarra or rishonim. To not get bogged down with these novella he put them in brackets so you could skip them.

Comment: @Bachur613: Also, as someone who learns Arukh haShulchan Yomi, a warning... He rarely explains enough for you to fully understand those novella. Rather, you often have to see the gemara or rishon inside to know what he is talking about. Contemporary publishing would probably use footnotes, as it's clearly "extra material" and not assumed to be the core text everyone would read. (That said, I try my best...)